# Velocity Template include master template

Tags: templates, velocity

I am working with Velocity templates, where I need to have multiple pages that needs to follow the same template style, say "about_me", "contact_us" and "home", all these pages will have same header, left menu and only thing different is content. 
For example, HTML for all of them would be exactly the same except for one in < div id="page-content" >.

```
<html>
  <head>
    .. some common css and js 
  </head>

   <body>
    <div id="main-content">
     <div id="header"> 
       Main Menu Bar on top 
     </div>
     <div id="left-menu"> 
       Menus on the left
     </div>
     <div id="page-content"> 
       I could be contact us, or home or about us.
     </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

One of the ways I have done is by having separate .vm file for header and side menu and importing them over on each of aboutus.vm, contactus.vm and home.vm, but with this i have lot of duplicate code. Is there a way to define everything as  a template and just have "page-content", defined in my .vm files?

Answer (score 3):

You could parse a velocity file in the middle of your page and define the template name as a variable. That way you could point to a different page-content.vm file for each

In the below example $contentTemplate could equal any of the following:

- home/page-content.vm
- about/page-content.vm
- contact/page-content.vm

See below

```
<html>
  <head>
    .. some common css and js 
  </head>

   <body>
    <div id="main-content">
     <div id="header"> 
       Main Menu Bar on top 
     </div>
     <div id="left-menu"> 
       Menus on the left
     </div>
     <div id="page-content"> 
       #parse($contentTemplate)
     </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, so this way I just have this 1 page say, I named it "main.html", and I have to pass "contentTemplate" from the controller? for all controllers using this template will use same view file?

Comment: Yeah that's right... you might prefer to pass something like "home" or "about" into the velocity context, rather than the actual filename, and then calcualte the filename from that value but that's up to you